# Phrase meaning “ты мой золотой”

Tags: перевод, словоупотребление, одним-словом, узус

I have been chatting with someone for a while now and she used the phrase “ты мой золотой” we have met before but currently we are in different country. My question is what does this phrase stand for? I know the meaning of the words. It says you are my gold but I don’t quite get what does she mean? Anyone care to explain pls? Thanks

Comment: By this word she shows she definitely wants you! I bet she's is fabulous Russian MILF:)

Comment: She’s not a milf, and not a gold digger... I have known her for a while now. But the issue now is that we are in different countries but we communicate everyday. So she doesn’t have any reason to keep communicating with me. Therefore I believe

Comment: I believe she has a strong sympathy to you, or maybe doing some sort of intimation by this.

Comment: It also depends of how often she use this word. I can say that this is NOT common address to person in Russia, but it may be usual in her personal background and just mean nothing. It depends.

Comment: Interesting, i will never know :D, she did mention that she likes me several times and when she was here we had some moments but ye idk xD

Comment: Then it's obviously sympathy:) It's meaningful to her.

Comment: Sympathy? What do you meab

Comment: Sympathy means only sympathy - like in the first definition of this word in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sympathy). I see no ambiguity here. One also call this affinity

Comment: I know what does it mean lol, but why sympathy it’s not a compliment xD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This phrase can have a wide range of meanings, in general it has an old-fashioned connotation and is often used by women of older generation as they speak to a younger collocutor and want to say how they like her/him, with shades of condescension, patronage, tenderness, gratitude.

As you mentioned it literally means "you are my gold", with variant "*ты мое золотце*", gold means as usual something valuable, dear.

Examples:

- Mother can say this to her child, if it helped her/did something useful, what she did not awaited it could do
- Grandmother can thank this way in general any younger person who helped her
- Of course the expression can be used by any person with footsie connotation, as a joke, to ironically express aforementioned condescension, patronage

Comment: But it’s used by a girl which I think is my gf xD what does that mean then?

Comment: See 3rd example then

Comment: So you mean it was a joke or sarcastic only?

Comment: I'd say it is flirtation

Comment: Sarcasm it basically evil irony, it is too hard for this expression

Comment: It was written through text so I can’t know

Comment: Well this expression can express rather irony/flirt, not sarcasm

Comment: when impersonating like gypsy fake fortuneteller it could border with sarcasm, but that is a corner case indeed, and such impersonation would include more phrases and specific words than just this single one.

Answer (score 3):

I think it depends on the depth of context/ meaningfulness of her heart's intentions, she may show her afection this way, along the lines of "You're my sweetie/ such a sweetheart/ darling/ You're my guy/my dear/ You're my precious"... or not, we'd need to read the whole message history to gauge what's what, lol.